# How to horizontally center a vbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes

I am using the [MIT Thesis templates](http://web.mit.edu/thesis/tex/templates.zip) to write my thesis.  I have created my own document class (that reflects the needs of the university I'm studying at) based on the `mitthesis.cls` version.  Since it is possible to have more than one supervisor, the MIT class implements a `vbox` for storing the list of supervisors and a command to add them.  The main problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to horizontally center the `vbox` containing the supervisor list.  It is always displayed aligned to the left margin. The code below is what I'm working with.

```
\supervisor{First Supervisor}   <= add 1st supervisor
\supervisor{Second Supervisor}  <= add 2nd supervisor
[...]
% store the supervisor list in a box
\newbox\@titlesupervisor
% since there can be more than one supervisor,
% we build the box for the titlepage
% as the user makes multiple calls
% to \supervisor
\def\supervisor#1{\setbox\@titlesupervisor\vbox
  {\unvbox\@titlesupervisor \vskip 10pt
   \def\baselinestretch{1}\large
   {#1}
  }
}
[...]
% Print the supervisor list after the heading, author, etc.
\textbf{Supervisor(s)}\par
\unvbox\@titlesupervisor
\vfill
```

I don't fully understand what `\unvbox` does, but I think it has something to do with vertical margin expansion to fit the text because if I remove the last `\unvbox`, the first supervisor disappears in the pdf.

Another problem I have is that I can't figure out is how to determine the number of entries in the supervisor list so I can decide whether to print "Supervisor" singularly or plurally?  Do I need to implement a counter in the add command or can I get the number somehow from the supervisor#1 or titlesupervisor variables?

Comment: By using that code, you just get paragraphs, so lines as wide as the `\hsize`, so there's no hope of “centering” them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with a different strategy:

```
\let\@titlesupervisor\@empty % initialize
\newif\if@supervisors
\def\supervisor#1{%
  \ifx\@titlesupervisor\@empty
    % do nothing, it's the first
  \else
    \@supervisorstrue % more than one supervisor
  \fi
  \g@addto@macro\@titlesupervisor{#1\\}%
}

[...]
% Print the supervisor list after the heading, author, etc.
\begin{center}
  \if@supervisors
    \textbf{Supervisors}
  \else
    \textbf{Supervisor}
  \fi
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \@titlesupervisor
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: The supervisor list is left justified.  How would I center align within the list?

Comment: Fixed it by using `{tabular}{@{}c@{}}`.  Later I found that I didn't need `tabular` at all; just needed to place a `\\ ` after `\@titlesupervisor`.  
I did need to put a `\par` inbetween the 'Supervisor' label and the list.